# Are there any statutory bodies or laws regarding the study and reccomendation to the government on prisons and penal laws ? (India)

Tags: india

I'm doing research on prisoners, parole laws and prison conditions as well as the criminal justice system in India. And the laws I found on this topic weren't many.

There is the Law Commission of India which is not a permanent organisation. https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_Commission_of_India

And then there is the national human rights commission.
https://www.indiacode.nic.in/handle/123456789/15709

Which has the mandate to study the conditions of prisoners in state prisons and make recommendations to the state government but it isn't mandated to recommend on topics like sentencing policies and the like and it only applies to prison Conditions and not punishments.

Are there any laws or statutory bodies that make recommendations on sentencing policies and prison reform in India?

Comment: a relevant blog https://blog.ipleaders.in/all-about-sentencing-in-india/  according to which, no permanent body exists that is an analogue of the UK sentencing council.

Comment: i see. I even looked up https://prsindia.org/ to see if there are any bills and laws that are being drafted or passed on this topic but there seem to be none

Comment: The [National Human Rights Commission](https://nhrc.nic.in/contact-us/special-monitor) covers jails as part of the Criminal Justice System brief. I don't know enough about Indian politics to know if it has actually produced recommendations or done research. Possibly other human rights and equality bodies would have an interest. Not sure if any organisation exclusively focuses on it.

Comment: recently the minister of Home affairs of India talked about bringing a model prisons act in the upcoming months. maybe that's a place to look at ?